# How can we discover what version of Jasmine Chutzpah is tied to?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

Since Chutzpah is tied to a specific Jasmine version, is there a way of finding which version it's tied to?

The [command line options](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Command-Line-Options) don't reveal any `--jasmineVersion`-like flag.

I looked at the [`package.json`](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/blob/master/package.json) file and see:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.38"
},
```

If we look up that [typings package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jasmine/v/2.5.38), we find:

> This package contains type definitions for Jasmine 2.5

This is a roundabout way of discovering the Jasmine version, and it assumes that the developer is updating the typings when jasmine is updated.

I found [this github issue](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/724) asking about the Jasmine version where the creator of chutzpah asks what version is needed, the dev says:

> As a minimum, we'd need Jasmine 2.6.0

And the creator says:

> Done, published 4.4

Looks like that roundabout method of finding the jasmine version did not work after all.

Is there a more direct way of figuring this out?

---

I did just discover that you can execute `jasmine.version` when the unit tests are being run, but I was hoping there was a way of doing this without actually running the unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback/question. I added a section for now on the readme on the GitHub page.

```
Test Framework Versions

Qunit 2.6.2
Jasmine 2.9
Mocha 3.2.0
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Also, it might be nice to list jasmine versions for older Chutzpah versions, so there's some record of it.